Having an issue with formatting
I am following this guide to learn how to develop a p2p messaging application. the guide seems out of date and i have having trouble displaying 2 things properly
<TabsTrigger value="login" className="data-[state=active]:bg-transparent text-black text-opacity-90 border-b-2 rounded-none w-full data-[state=active]:text-black data-[state=active]:font-semibold data-[state=active]:border-b-purple-500 p-3 transition-all duration-300">Login</TabsTrigger>
i would like to display these 2 next to each other not one on top of the other
image
i tried different css styles and i havent gotten it.
i was expecting login / signup to be horizontal not vertical

Welcome to stackoverflow, if you need help you can provide a minimal reproducible example so we can see what's happening

you can view it on my github @ftpggversed under the realtime messaging repo and in the file src/pages/auth/index.jsx

You should follow some guides on the basics of CSS, then one on Tailwind.

You should wrap TabsList around the TabsTrigger of the Login and Signup components. You can set the className of TabsList to be either flex or grid to transform it from being vertical to horizontal. Typically, you can set the className as follows: className="grid w-full grid-cols-2". You can check the Shadcn docs on how to use Tabs here: https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/tabs

@HamedJimoh ill try this and let you know how it works when i get back to my computer

You should wrap TabsList around the TabsTrigger of the Login and Signup components. You can set the className of TabsList to be either flex or grid to transform it from being vertical to horizontal. Typically, you can set the className as follows:
<TabsList className="grid w-full grid-cols-2">
    <TabsTrigger value="login" className="data-[state=active]:bg-transparent text-black text-opacity-90 border-b-2 rounded-none w-full data-[state=active]:text-black data-[state=active]:font-semibold data-[state=active]:border-b-purple-500 p-3 transition-all duration-300">Login</TabsTrigger>
    <TabsTrigger value="signup" className="data-[state=active]:bg-transparent text-black text-opacity-90 border-b-2 rounded-none w-full data-[state=active]:text-black data-[state=active]:font-semibold data-[state=active]:border-b-purple-500 p-3 transition-all duration-300">Signup</TabsTrigger>
</TabsList>

Or you can use flex like this:
<TabsList className="w-full flex space-x-6">
    <TabsTrigger value="login" className="data-[state=active]:bg-transparent text-black text-opacity-90 border-b-2 rounded-none w-full data-[state=active]:text-black data-[state=active]:font-semibold data-[state=active]:border-b-purple-500 p-3 transition-all duration-300">Login</TabsTrigger>
    <TabsTrigger value="signup" className="data-[state=active]:bg-transparent text-black text-opacity-90 border-b-2 rounded-none w-full data-[state=active]:text-black data-[state=active]:font-semibold data-[state=active]:border-b-purple-500 p-3 transition-all duration-300">Signup</TabsTrigger>
</TabsList>

You can check the Shadcn docs on how to use Tabs here: ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/tabs
